# Power amp current source reserve requirements

Tags: current-source, power-amplifier

[image]

If I use current sources in power amplifier need I make it current value 5 or more times greater than the next stage may consume? For example if I drive 6 amp current though load I may found that 6/(betta_MJL3281A * betta_2N6473) = 6/(75 * 15) = 5ma. Need I set Q5 emitter resistor (0,65 * 2/25ma) to drive 25ma current (with reserve) or I may drive without reserve, i.e. 5ma?

Comment: I'd replace the diodes with a \$V_{BE}\$ multiplier (and include an Early Effect collector resistor in it), perhaps replace \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ with Darlington equivalents, and specify IC-based BJTs for current mirrors and the input BJTs -- such as BCV61/BCV62, BCM61/BCM62, etc., depending on the matching you want. Otherwise, you need a beta compensation resistors and \$V_{BE}\$ compensation emitter degeneration at the very least. Otherwise, I see some good things here (Miller-comp cap \$C_3\$.) It's a judgment call regarding that current -- but it should be "stiff" enough.

Comment: If I use BCV46 darlington instead of Q1 and Q2 how much I may increase R10 to increase effective amplification of an amplifier?

Comment: How I can calc emitter degeneration resistors for Q12, Q19. I find that recommended value of Re = 50mv / desired_diff_stage_current

Comment: What else are popular small-power darlingtons?

Comment: All tips are very useful! But may you also check my original question. Need I make current source to drive more current 2 or 5 times that the load of that current source may consume?

Comment: 5X is probably okay. But I spent only a cursory glance over your circuit. So I'm just giving you an idea about what I've seen used (and used) before in other circuits where I spent more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the error-amplifier (diffpair) has high voltages emitter-collector, and moderate or high collector current, the diffpair will generate high transient thermal distortion **unless** the diffpair share the same silicon die and indeed are interdigitated at the 10micron level.

At 1mm separation, on silicon, the coupling Tau is 11,400 seconds / 100*100*100 or 11.4 milliseconds (14 Hertz F3dB).

At 100 micron separation, coupling tau is 114 microseconds (or 1,400 Hz F3dB).

At 10 micron separation, coupling tau is 1.14 microseconds (140KHz, suitable for quality audio).

To prevent this heat-originated thermal distortion, use cascodes (common base) devices. The UA715 opamp used this method.

edit for more historical details

I recall a comment on bipolar thermal distortion in medical instrumentation being a KNOWN problem back in the 1960s.

My own investigation into bipolar thermal issues came from self-destruction of
bipolar output drivers in chip-chip interface circuits. Operating at 4 milliAmps per (20 by 100micron) emitter strip, the bipolars entered thermal runaway at about 15 volts across the device. Eventually we found papers discussing the equivalent thermal-resistance of on-chip bipolars, determined by the emitter area; this makes sense because the emitter-base junction is what controls the current, even tho the heat is dissipated in collector junction almost entirely; in vertical-transistor-layout, the EB junction is surrounded by the CB junction, with thermal-taus of 1nanosecond to a few microseconds (0.2U distance to 20u distance in HighVoltage bipolars).

Using these tidbits

----- deltaVeb = -2 milliVolts/degree Centigrade

----- thermal-resistance is 200 degree Centigrade/watt

----- Collector dissipation of Vce * Ic

----- delta_Icollector/deltaVbe = 10%/4 milliVolts

You perform a perturbation analysis [I'll write this up later] to find the loop gain. You make Vce = 15 volts, Ic = 4mA, and the loop gain is approximately ONE.
A loop gain of ONE (+ ONE) indicates the point where exponential growth starts.

Thus you can use these small equations to predict thermal-runaway.

For audio distortion, you don't need thermal-runaway, just some overshooting of currents during transients.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to understand how commercial amps work from reputable Japanese designs, and see the purpose of each component, you may learn how to improve quality.

[image]

Of course there are many details in thermal matching and hFE binning needed as well.  Here TR110 acts as the Vbe multiplier which must be thermally attached to the output stages.  Tuning is performed with Pot VR101.

There is also OCP output protection with TR113,114 with 0.47R sense and OVP input protection with diodes and 47pF and an input RC complex network for spectral coupling and noise rejection.

Each component here is carefully selected for many reasons with careful selection of caps for transient input and load response.

Next is a similar one from the same company, slightly newer.
[image]